# how can i design MSSQL database structure?

Tags: sql-server

my scenario is one property (idproperty) has one meter (meterInfo_id), or several properties share one meter, should i consider it many-to-many or one-to-many relationship? if it is many-to-many relationship, how do i design? Thanks for helping.

[image]

Comment: I would say one to many as you only have one meter but have 1 or more properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `meterInfo_id` column to your `property` table. It is a 1-to-m relation.

Answer (score 0):

As per my Understanding Meter has One property or Multiple Properties 
so relation Between this two Entity would be **One to Many**..
So you Should add **Meter Id** to **Property** Table

Answer (score 0):

This is one to many relations from MeterInfo to Property table. Create new column in property table as foreign key of meterinfo_id.

Answer (score 0):

One Property has one meter OR many properties can share one meter BUT one property can not have many meters So it is not many to many relationship.  Now many properties can share one meter then you must have meter_id column in your property table. Hence It is One to Many Relationship from meter to property table.